# Google spreadsheet Pie Chart Consistent coloring

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

in Google Spreadsheet we have color inconsistencies in the Pie Charts slices within the same spreadsheet. We can set colors for slices with values that exist, but when a new value appears, it sets a random new color.
How could we use either UI or App Script to ensure that the colors of a Slice Pie for all Pies in a spreadsheet are consistent with a set of values?
Thank you in advance

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7owoC.png)

Comment: Are you creating the charts using Apps Script, the Sheets API, or the Web UI?

Comment: There are methods to do this in the UI by creating a chart using a lookup table against all expected categories as the source and preallocating the colours - with this approach any categories with null/zero values don't appear, and those that do appear have a consistent colour. But this is very difficult to demonstrate without some example data to show how it might apply to your situation!

Comment: I'm creating the charts using Web UI directly.